# php openssl - RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2 and RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:padding check failed:rsa_eay.c:602:

Tags: php, ssl, encryption, openssl, rsa

I´m having a hard time understanding what is my problem here, so i was hopping someone could help me. So, i have a xml file which was build respecting W3C [recomendations](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlenc-core1/#sec-Introduction)and because of this, there are specific tags which were encrypted with my public key, and now i need to decrypt them using my private key, so for example this chunck of code:

```
<AuthenticatedPrivate Id="ID_AuthenticatedPrivate">
        <enc:EncryptedKey xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
            <enc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p" />
            <enc:CipherData>
                <enc:CipherValue>lwYdkG5Q5wfW/S7UzZDtnJMcAng3w3ketzkh68y1BeX+okNEj48b5rSWUC/4mNhT
N2QsHxOCkvKDavIGGSAP23tdp0VtdeHTNAszcgK4Xzc8VHGUEiswONCOxTzNWuwj
....
zfHceeHN50b8vzM/Rt/jTUq54eC3nE+lP3eTXbLj/YvpPo8H45Sti9YP9WZixGHz
Uvf6Go31+3JwsXXIUl3O+w==</enc:CipherValue>
            </enc:CipherData>
        </enc:EncryptedKey>
        <enc:EncryptedKey xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
            <enc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p" />
            <enc:CipherData>
                <enc:CipherValue>TvC1LCspgTsXqM1b8ClPCtAkAdXXzxe+Av7LMxYtUaqUbd8HeBuaS1cx3WwoVRDr
TWcrBEnv24GbIB5ygcMFW3DlGsXfmWJGnRNx/6xT/U15RQPgoD9AP4WFEHxthzP0
....
1ajG5lDjEu4TqjdL7DPGNu9HfI9boerJ5FUFQ/fMdD4xbDHdc4DgIQdTUgLFGHJz
RwOyfOAcSNoO/fpAkMXoEw==</enc:CipherValue>
            </enc:CipherData>
        </enc:EncryptedKey>
    </AuthenticatedPrivate>
```

I need to decrypt that, so what i have done was:

1. Parsed the xml, and got the tag i need (CipherValue).And actually putted that inside a file, cypher.xml
2. cat cypher.xml| base64 -D > rawFile
3. openssl rsautl -decrypt -in rawFile -out plaintext -inkey private.pem

and the result was:

```
4476804716:error:0407109F:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:pkcs decoding error:rsa_pk1.c:273:
4476804716:error:04065072:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:padding check failed:rsa_eay.c:602:
```

What am i missing here? i´m losing too much time on this, i saw something about using the padding, but i did that directly on my php app using:

```
openssl_private_decrypt($tag, $decrypted, $privkey, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);
```

but with NO! luck at all.

Thanks for your time, regards

**EDIT**

The code sequence i´m using is this:

```
$xmlFile = file_get_contents(path_to_my_xml_file);
$privkey = openssl_pkey_get_private(path_to_my_private_key);
$arrCplContent =  XmlToArray::convert($xmlFile);
$tag = $arrCplContent['AuthenticatedPrivate']['enc:EncryptedKey'][0]['enc:CipherData']['enc:CipherValue'];
$b64Dec = base64_decode($tag);
$result = openssl_private_decrypt($b64Dec, $decrypted, $privkey, OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);
```

when i log this, the result is:

```
error:04099079:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1:oaep decoding error
```

Is this the proper way of doing things, considering [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlenc-core1/#sec-Introduction) ?.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it seems you are using PKCS#1 v1.5 padding instead of OAEP padding when performing the decryption. You can see  [`OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING` listed for `openssl_private_decrypt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-private-decrypt.php).

Note the line in the XML document containing the OAEP padding indication:

> <enc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p" />

There are two `CipherValue` elements in there. Usually that means that the ciphertext was created using two different key pairs and thus two separate private keys. You may just need to decrypt the other `EncryptedKey`.

To solve this in general: XML encryption or XML enc is a [full standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlenc-core/), and you need to either implement the standard or - what's commonly recommended - [use a library](https://github.com/robrichards/xmlseclibs) to decrypt it.

Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with the shown library, and I don't have any opinion on it's security.

Comment: Hi Maarten, first of all thank you for answering, i´m really stuck on this, i have edited my question, could you please take a look? Regards

Comment: The problem with these kind of questions is that it is basically debugging, but for us without a debugging environment. Check if you try both values that I've indicated, and compare before trying to decrypt. And pretty please with sugar on top, make sure that you've got the right key, or you will get padding error till the end of time. Note that there is a hash that needs to be configured for OAEP; usually this is not the problem, but it is something you can check if all else fails.